# How to filter angular json file dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to search my json file based on the letters I'm typing it should be filtered accordingly, Here's my json file:

```
constructor(private service:ServiceService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.x="123";
     this.service.getListofTurbines(this.x).subscribe(s=>{
     this.rslt=s;

 })
```

with filter it returns me the right match,but how can i search it dynamically?

Comment: what do you mean dynamically ?

Comment: @TonyBarletta when i write a letter in inputer box,i want the json file to be filetred accordingly

Comment: If you are using a text input use a FormControl and subscribe to valueChange observable to filter the value on the fly.

Comment: @TonyBarletta can you give me a sample or an example?

Answer (score 0):

Typing is an action that occurs in control therefore in angular the best way to do is if you create a `FormGroup` and a `FormControl`

For the sake of the example we will call your form **`listForm`** and your control **`searchControl`**

```
  listForm: FormGroup;
```

...

```
//this could on ngOnInit declaring the formControl and the formGroup
   this.listForm = this.formBuilder.
   group({ item: this.formBuilder.array([]), 
      'searchControl': new FormControl("") });
```

...

```
//this could on ngOnInit observing the value changes when typing occurs
    this.listForm.controls['searchControl'].valueChanges .pipe(
          startwith(''),
          debounceTime(500) /*to avoid searching every letter, increase time to reduce searches*/)
          .subscribe((value) => {
              //and here your perform your search
```

Comment: the last part can you explain about startwith()?you mean str.startwith?

Comment: To ensure the value is a string

Comment: filter is also possible